# How to Resolve TypeScript Error with Clone Function for Generic Interface

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a video editor in JavaScript, and I've encountered a TypeScript error related to a generic interface used in my code.

I'm getting an error in the onCloneAny function:

```
Argument of type 'AnyClipType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'TextClip & VideoClip' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'TextClip' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I am getting this error when trying to call `clone` method on `AnyClipType` variable type.

```js
interface Clip<T extends AnyClipType> {
    type: string;
    clone: (clone: T) => T;
    // here Clip interface also have `destroy`, `setup`, `serialize`, `deserialize` methods that receives `T`
}

interface TextClip extends Clip<TextClip> {
    type: 'text';
    text: string;
}

interface VideoClip extends Clip<VideoClip> {
    type: 'video';
    src: string;
}

type AnyClipType = TextClip | VideoClip;

const textClip: TextClip = {
    type: 'text',
    text: 'Hello',
    clone(clone) {
        // I want TS property completions here
        // depending on the clip type being created
        // here, for example, TS compiler successfully infers `clone` is type TextClip
        clone.text
        return clone;
    }
}

function onCloneAny(clip: AnyClipType) {
    // Argument of type 'AnyClipType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
    // The intersection 'TextClip & VideoClip' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    // Type 'TextClip' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    const newClip = clip.clone(clip);
}

function onCloneText(clip: TextClip) {
    const newClip = clip.clone(clip);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBtgAcA8AVZCAD0hABMBnZAQRAE8Ns86sIA%20ZAbwFgAoZAcjAsIALmQUwUUAHMA3H0HIE6APYgxyABQr1mvAEpkAXg54F-QQHoryABbQUjLMlCRYiFHHQVV9uABuKAAGZBCSUKp0wQA0yMEUEGAArlix8YnS3sAAXhDpoeHQwNl5wcgAtkl2qpRCdnBgyFAQSMBBVMF4wXwAvnx8btDwSMh4xGDOhCQQ5FTO%20BPOHDyWAsKs4gDkkCRbFkq7YOIRshb9vIPgw57IAGrAYapTE7N1Cw9Py1yKghuaWwCjwgqn2vwEFCgCBOUjOfQGvH%20NHozmYrBMYyWmBcAB97sDntiLHwEOpJEIsdhxOMSFNjD81kIRNsjlsYuCKSRtgAJCDoNRsjm6DQ6NQaIyrJRKGzIACSyAA7nBwGMAMrILCRVhQYTKVQVLDoJLAMn2Rwc6W2MKsciyZDqeooFTYJnogBGEDtCBajQgZAt1lsDhacRgqig0zgBqNcTw6tJBuARojFGSCCQFAoMGS-LorhAMGgnWF%20VcVCRNMm2IDAhLADojjXmklklAQMoxRADoILhc%20NmQAgwCb2%20oMHpaHRRVTkQxsWiIBKOTLqFAZMkqirVDBXSgtpPUSItmXkCBVE04JngDIQHA3UahH4sHAoFGktB7TukVsNEEoFs62XWw8AcfN3ESIcR2QLZKymAAyfEvmxY8lSoFoyDTP1H2g39oGPD0EDgZJEg1LVoF1HYj38KhSQLTBIJAGRdyoUAJH1J0yWHFJZjAChAMZGUF2g2DkJPM8LyvG87wfMA-G-XD-34pRaPJDQFTpDtsDrEtpywAxzgRAdIIdMdO0rXTqUpPSGWUzjTwgdTsQxZ0sG0ztdP0%20FeCAA)

Comment: You might be looking for [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) as demonstrated [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVO15m). Does that meet your needs? If so then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear to me what's your actual context.

For instance, if the `clone` method's goal is to clone the object itself, why specifying an input?

However, here is a solution in case you can get rid of the `clone` argument. Otherwise, I'll remove this answer.

```
interface Clip<T extends AnyClipType> {
    type: string;
    clone: () => T;
    // here Clip interface also have `destroy`, `setup`, `serialize`, `deserialize` methods that receives `T`
}

interface TextClip extends Clip<TextClip> {
    type: 'text';
    text: string;
}

interface VideoClip extends Clip<VideoClip> {
    type: 'video';
    src: string;
}

type AnyClipType = TextClip | VideoClip;

const textClip: TextClip = {
    type: 'text',
    text: 'Hello',
    clone() {
        // "this" holds the properties of this object
        return { ...this };
    }
}

function onCloneAny(clip: AnyClipType) {
    const newClip = clip.clone();
}

function onCloneText(clip: TextClip) {
    const newClip = clip.clone();
}
```